# Converting Float to String

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql-server

I am importing an Excel sheet to SQL, and it is getting stored in table1. I am then
copying the data from table1 to table2 with the below query:

```
insert into table1(JOB_ID ,JOB_NAME)
select isnull(JOB_ID,'') ,isnull(JOB_NAME,'') from table2$
```

But my requirement is, when it's getting imported from Excel to SQL table the datatype of `JOB_ID` is automatically gone to `Float`.So when am copying that data into another table the values in `table2-JOB_ID` are in `float`.but i need it in string or varchar .

Comment: Doesn't Convert.ToString() do the job?

Comment: importing using the import wizard?

Comment: What are you using to import the Excel sheet into SQL Server? SSIS? C# code?

Comment: If you use C# at all. To extract the data from Excel, or for copying the information from table to table, you can always use .ToString() at some point. Isn't it?

Comment: am importing using Import wizard.

Comment: How are mysql and sql-server *both* tagged in this question?

Comment: and am writing a Stored procedure

Comment: import wizard allows for variable changes to import values under the edit mappings button and you can map columns to new types

Comment: @DavidScott - make this an answer so the OP can give you credit for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import wizard allows for variable changes to import values under the edit mappings button and you can map columns to new types

Hope this helps